# VSTS: Retrieve TestRun (RunType = Automated) by Test Run Id

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve TestRun based on Test Run ID (Run Type = Automated) but it returns null. If the test run id is Manual then it returns TestRun object. Is there any option to retrieve Automated Test Run based on ID?

```
var tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(vstsCollectionUrl), new VssClientCredentials());
tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

var testMgmtService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
var testMgmtTeamProject = testMgmtService.GetTeamProject(vstsProject);

var testRun = testMgmtTeamProject.TestRuns.Find(testRunId);

var testResults = testRun.QueryResultsByStatus(TestResultState.InProgress);
```

Comment: What's the version of the assemblies? Try it with [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package (Create a new project and install this package)

Comment: I am using the same package. `<package id="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" version="15.112.1" targetFramework="net46" />`. My observation is, If the TestRun type is Automated then TestRuns.Find method returns null value.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, check whether team project you specified is correct. On the other hand, try it with another test run (Automated).